# How To Remove a Line After The Error Output

Tags: bash, proxy, grep

How do I remove the a text after an error output?
As example I have script, need using proxy but after awhile it showing error:

> [05:16:35 List: list.txt] 101/31. PROXY ERROR => yrros@hotmail.com

I want to remove the the proxy from the line to make sure this error wont affect the next output, so the other scanning wont print any PROXY ERROR from previous Proxy.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please show us the expected output.

Comment: @User123 Do you mean the positive output? its `[05:16:21 List: list.txt] 97/35. LIVE => yqureshi@hotmail.com` and the negative is `[05:16:24 List: list.txt] 131/1. DIE => yuris_alert2@hotmail.com`

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the answer with putting `sed`

```
 printf "[$header] $2/$3. ${RED}PROXY ERROR => $1 ${NC}"
 echo "$rand_proxy" >> proxy_error.txt
 sed -i "/$rand_proxy/d" proxyGUD.txt
```

It will deleting the error proxy